# How can two iPhone applications share the same settings?

Tags: iphone

Can two different iPhone applications share the same settings?  I'm releasing two iPhone products, one that requires the user to login to use, the other that is free and can be used without a login.  However, the second free application could have some enhancements that we could give if the user were logged in.  Would it be possible to let a user who has both apps installed use the same settings module for the username/password we store on the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. I believe that each Settings module that is related to your app ID, which will be different for each app. It would be a security risk if one application could access another's settings.

I think the best solution is to use some sort of web service to store/retrieve the settings. Or you could use a custom URL scheme to pass data between the applications if you don't want to use a web service.

Comment: "you could use a custom URL scheme" what a great idea! Up vote for cleverness and simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Natively I dont think its possible. But interfacing with an Internet Web Service, you could do it.